# Reading only numbers from file input

Tags: java

While reading in a simple file, I'm trying to only take the numbers from it.

```
Hi 80 
Bye 90
Cool 100
```

Using a scanner delimiter of a tab space will help me ignore the space before the number but when I try to grab the number itself it grabs something like 80Bye afterwards. Is there any fix for this?

Edit:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("score.txt"));
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");

        while( scan.hasNext() ){
            name=scan.next();
            System.out.println(name);// Prints Hi
            num=scan.next();
            scan.nextLine();
            scan.delimiter();
            System.out.println(num); //Prints 80
                                     //       Bye
            holdAvg+=Integer.parseInt(num); // Error occurs

            count++;
        }
```

When I try to take in the number 80, Bye follows right after it. I've tried using a "\n" delimiter too but it does not work either. When I use"\n" it says theres an error with " 100" becoming an int when I try to parse it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show some code?

Comment: Read the file line by line. Split the line(s) on white space.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for this.

Comment: You can try reading lines from the file, split the output for spaces. That should get you 80. You can also use regular expressions as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just catch the exception if it is thrown.

```
try {
    holdAvg += Integer.parseInt(num);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // silently catch exception
}
```

And messing with the delimiter probably won't help you here. Scanners default to using any white space for the delimiter, which should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to set an explicit delimiter, the default(whitespace) will do fine:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("score.txt"));

    while( scan.hasNext() )
    {
        System.out.println("Word: " + scan.next());
        System.out.println("Number: " + scan.nextInt());
    }
```

A try catch block would be useful to make sure your program doesn't crash when it gets unexpected input.
`Integer.parseInt(..)` throws a `NumberFormatException` and `scan.nextInt()` throws a `InputMismatchException`.

See the javadoc on Scanner: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html